# Defining potential energy for a non-conservative field with a global attractor

Tags: vector-fields, conservative-field

Consider a vector field $\vec{F}(\vec{x})$ that is not necessarily conservative (meaning that the line integral of this field need not be path-independent). If we now describe the motion of a particle as the first order ODE:

$$ \dot{\vec{x}}=F(\vec{x})$$

Now, assume there is a stationary point that is also a global attractor. In other words, there is a unique point $\vec{x_0}$ such that $F(\vec{x_0})=0$, and the particle will always end up at $\vec{x_0}$ regardless of it's initial position.

Is it possible to define a "potential energy" of this field relative to the global attractor? For example:

$$ V(\vec{x})=\int_{\gamma(\vec{x})} \vec{F}(\vec{s})\cdot{d\vec{s}}$$

where $\gamma(\vec{x})$ is the path that the particle follows from $\vec{x}$ to $\vec{x_0}$ (the global attractor). Note that there is only one unique path that the particle can follow as its velocity is uniquely determined by the field, thus the "potential" is well-defined at any given point.

Does this formulation make any sense? And if so, is this formulation used in any particular area of physics? I'm asking because I'm currently working on a project that requires the construction of a scalar field from a non-conservative vector field.

Comment: Don't you mean that a line integral involving this field will be path-dependent?

Comment: Yes, nice catch. Edited.

Comment: I think the problem is that you are thinking about F being the only force on the particle, but this might not be the case. Therefore, there is not only one path the particle can travel on for a given initial position, since other forces could alter this. However, you could break your non-conservative field into a sum of curless and non-curless components. Then you could have something like apotential, but with an extra term.